# Ruby On Rails initializers - handle engine migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I'm creating application with Rails Engine (RoR3) and I want it's migration to be run when host app migration run. Without copying them. So far I found this solution:

http://pivotallabs.com/leave-your-migrations-in-your-rails-engines/

It's number 3.
I would like to use the code (below) not in engine.rb but in config/initializers.

```
initializer :append_migrations do |app|
  unless app.root.to_s.match root.to_s
    app.config.paths["db/migrate"] += config.paths["db/migrate"].expanded
  end
end
```

Any hint how this could be achieved?
Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're not on Rails 4? Just curious. Building versus legacy versions is always a bit risky.

Comment: I agree but this project has dependencies and other engines written with Rails 3. That's what we're doing, it isn't really my choice. ;)

Comment: Thought that might be the case, but just had to note it. They do fix up things like this in more recent releases.